# Can't see my text using SDL TTF for SDL 2

Tags: c++, unicode, sdl-ttf, sdl-2

I guess I do all right, but anyway I don't see my text. [Official docs](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/docs/SDL_ttf_45.html) are poor (or obsolete for SDL 2).

```
if (TTF_Init())
    printf("%s\n", TTF_GetError());
font = TTF_OpenFont("Fonts/DinCompRegular.ttf", 24);
if (!font)
    printf("%s\n", TTF_GetError());
SDL_Color fontColor = { 255, 0, 0, 255 };
u16 text[] = { '2', 's', 'ä', 'Щ' };
SDL_Surface *info = TTF_RenderUNICODE_Solid(font, text, fontColor);
SDL_Rect rect = { info->w, info->h, 0, 0 };
SDL_Surface *place = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0, info->w, info->h, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

And in main loop:

```
    SDL_BlitSurface(info, 0, place, &rect);
    SDL_FreeSurface(info);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by myself:

```
u16 text[] = { '2', L'Щ', L'ä', L'Ø', '\0' };
SDL_Surface *info = TTF_RenderUNICODE_Blended(font, text, fontColor);
```

Loop:

```
    SDL_Texture *texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, info);
    SDL_Rect src = { 0, 0, info->w, info->h };
    SDL_Rect dst = { 0, 0, info->w, info->h };
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, &src, &dst);
    SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
```